# Не компилируется

Tags: c++

```
#if defined(linux) || defined(_WIN32)
#include <GL/glut.h>    /*??? Linux ? Windows*/
#else
#include <GLUT/GLUT.h>  /*??? Mac OS*/
#endif
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int n,a=2,al=0,c=200;

    int X[100];
    int Y[100];
    int R[100];

void processNormalKeys(unsigned char key, int x, int y) {
int i=0;
if (key == 109) ::a-=10;
if (key == 112) ::a+=10;
if (key == 114) ::al+=1;
if (key == 108) ::al-=1;
if ((key == 109)||(key == 112)||(key == 114)||(key == 108)){
    for(i=0,i<(::n),i++){
        ::X[i]=::c+::a*::R[i]*cos(::al);
        ::Y[i]=::c+::a*::R[i]*sin(::al);
    }
}

}



void reshape(int w, int h)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluOrtho2D(0, w, 0, h);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
}

void display()
{
    int i = 0;
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glClear(GL_ACCUM_BUFFER_BIT);
    glClear(GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);

    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    for(i=0,i<::n,i++){
        glVertex2i(::X[i],::Y[i]);
    }
    glEnd();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}


int main (int argc, char * argv[])
{
    int i=0;
        FILE *f;
        f=fopen("in.txt","r");
        fscanf(f,"%i",&::n);
        for(i=0,i<::n,i++){
            fscanf(f,"%i",::X+i);
        };
        for(i=0,i<::n,i++){
            fscanf(f,"%i",::Y+i);
        };
        fclose(f);
        for(i=0,i<::n,i++){
            ::R[i]=floor(sqrt((::X[i]-::c)*(::X[i]-::c)+(::Y[i]-::c)*    (::Y[i]-::c)));
        };
        for(i=0,i<::n,i++){
            ::X[i]=::c+::a*::R[i]*cos(::al);
            ::Y[i]=::c+::a*::R[i]*sin(::al);
        };




    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE|GLUT_RGBA);
    glutInitWindowSize(800, 600);
    glutCreateWindow("OpenGL 1");
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);


    glutKeyboardFunc(processNormalKeys);
    glutDisplayFunc(display);


    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;
}
```

C:\Users\zxcvbnm\Documents\jjj\main.cpp In function 'void processNormalKeys(unsigned char, int, int)':
24  22  C:\Users\zxcvbnm\Documents\jjj\main.cpp [Error] expected ';' before ')' token
28  2   C:\Users\zxcvbnm\Documents\jjj\main.cpp [Error] expected primary-expression before '}' token
28  2   C:\Users\zxcvbnm\Documents\jjj\main.cpp [Error] expected ';' before '}' token
28  2   C:\Users\zxcvbnm\Documents\jjj\main.cpp [Error] expected primary-expression before '}' token
28  2   C:\Users\zxcvbnm\Documents\jjj\main.cpp [Error] expected ')' before '}' token
28  2   C:\Users\zxcvbnm\Documents\jjj\main.cpp [Error] expected primary-expression before '}' token
C:\Users\zxcvbnm\Documents\jjj\main.cpp In function 'void display()':
56  20  C:\Users\zxcvbnm\Documents\jjj\main.cpp [Error] expected primary-expression before ':' token
56  20  C:\Users\zxcvbnm\Documents\jjj\main.cpp [Error] expected ']' before ':' token
59  15  C:\Users\zxcvbnm\Documents\jjj\main.cpp [Error] could not convert 'glEnd()' from 'void' to 'bool'
60  26  C:\Users\zxcvbnm\Documents\jjj\main.cpp [Error] expected ')' before ';' token
C:\Users\zxcvbnm\Documents\jjj\main.cpp In function 'int main(int, char**)':
70  14  C:\Users\zxcvbnm\Documents\jjj\main.cpp [Error] expected primary-expression before ':' token
70  14  C:\Users\zxcvbnm\Documents\jjj\main.cpp [Error] expected ']' before ':' token
73  3   C:\Users\zxcvbnm\Documents\jjj\main.cpp [Error] expected primary-expression before 'for'
73  3   C:\Users\zxcvbnm\Documents\jjj\main.cpp [Error] expected ')' before 'for'
73  14  C:\Users\zxcvbnm\Documents\jjj\main.cpp [Error] expected primary-expression before ':' token
73  14  C:\Users\zxcvbnm\Documents\jjj\main.cpp [Error] expected ']' before ':' token
76  12  C:\Users\zxcvbnm\Documents\jjj\main.cpp [Error] expected ')' before ';' token
77  14  C:\Users\zxcvbnm\Documents\jjj\main.cpp [Error] expected primary-expression before ':' token
77  14  C:\Users\zxcvbnm\Documents\jjj\main.cpp [Error] expected ']' before ':' token
80  3   C:\Users\zxcvbnm\Documents\jjj\main.cpp [Error] expected primary-expression before 'for'
80  3   C:\Users\zxcvbnm\Documents\jjj\main.cpp [Error] expected ')' before 'for'
80  14  C:\Users\zxcvbnm\Documents\jjj\main.cpp [Error] expected primary-expression before ':' token
80  14  C:\Users\zxcvbnm\Documents\jjj\main.cpp [Error] expected ']' before ':' token
88  30  C:\Users\zxcvbnm\Documents\jjj\main.cpp [Error] expected ')' before ';' token
28      C:\Users\zxcvbnm\Documents\jjj\Makefile.win recipe for target 'main.o' failed

Comment: Это не читаемо, текст ошибки. `#if defined(linux) || defined(_WIN32)` - вот это точно не так..

Comment: @NewView это не важно. Первая ошибка в 24 строке

Comment: Ясное дело это там не единственное :) для себя я закончил просмотр кода на куче ифов вместо простого свича с кейсами.

Comment: Так компилятор  сам указывает на ошибку, и просто нужно читать

Comment: Разбирайтесь с ошибками по одной. Много вопросов в одном здесь нельзя.

Answer (score 1):

Как минимум, всякие

```
for(i=0,i<::n,i++)
```

должны быть

```
for(i=0;i<::n;i++)
```

(обратите внимание на точки с запятой).

Comment: с возвращением!  Надеюсь у вас все нормально....

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Спасибо!